# Removing all punctuation, spaces and other non-letter characters including numbers from a text file

Tags: python, text

I downloaded a book from gutenberg project and saved it as a text file.
I started to use the below code as initial steps.

```
Book_name = 'Animals.txt'                       
fd = open(Book_name, encoding='utf8')        
Animals = fd.read()                            
print (type(Animals), len(Animals))
words = Animals.split()
print(type(words), len(words))
fd.close()
```

I have read the book I chose (the text file), then I have done the below:

```
def remove_punc(string):
punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\, <>./?@#$%^&*_~12345678“90σ\nθμνëη=χéὁλςπε”οκ£ι§ρτυαωæδàγψ'''
for ele in string:  
    if ele in punc:  
        string = string.replace(ele, "") 
return string


try:
with open(filename,'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()
with open(filename,"w+",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(remove_punc(data))
print("Removed punctuations from the file", filename)
```

It didn't work, so I couldn't proceed with the rest

2nd solution below:
[image: 2nd solution below?]

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier like this?

```
from string import digits

    yourfile
    tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r"\w+")
    clean_text = tokenizer.tokenize(yourfile)
    my_string= (" ".join(clean_text))
    newstring = my_string.translate(None, digits)
    print(newstring)
```

that is, instead of removing what you don't want, get what you want.
You get your list of words, then turn that into a string, remove the numbers from the string with the translate method.

Comment: \w includes numbers as far as I'm aware, and the problem stated to not include them

Comment: thank you! Yes, but I would like to remove all characters, numbers and spaces too so my text file (the book) will basically be glued together, all sentences will be glued together with no spaces, numbers or punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand you correctly, you want to remove literally every character except for A-Z and a-z?

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[^A-Za-z]')
data = ''
with open(filename,'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = pattern.sub('', f.read())
with open(filename,"w+",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: thank you, Peter! Yes, so from my text file I downloaded, I want to remove everything: numbers, punctuation, and spaces too, so my text file will basically will be just words glued together

Comment: So did my solution work?

Comment: Not sure if I am doing it correctly. My downloaded file is called Animals. if I replace filename with Animals, it still doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Can you update your post with the full code?

Comment: Yes, good point. Just realized I haven't included the first bit! Thank you, Peter

Comment: @TheodoraMartha I need to see the way you are trying to use the code I gave in my answer, so I can see what is going wrong with it.

Comment: Added your code above too and the way I see it? I have included a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239331/discussion-between-theodora-martha-and-peter-white).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the translate() method.  First prepare a translation table that will remove punctuation.  Then use it directly on your input data to write the output.

```
punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\, <>./?@#$%^&*_~12345678“90σ\nθμνëη=χéὁλςπε”οκ£ι§ρτυαωæδàγψ'''

removePunctuation = str.maketrans('','',punc)   # translation table

with open(filename,'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()

with open(filename,"w+",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(data.translate(removePunctuation))  # use translate directly

print("Removed punctuations from the file", filename)
```

You seem to want more characters to be excluded than mere punctuation but you can get most of these characters from the string module:

```
import string

punc = ' ' + string.punctuation + string.digits + "your extra chars"
```